# Numbers having Unique (or Distinct) digits in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and trying to convert the java code of finding Numbers having Unique (or Distinct) digits in scala.
for example

```
Input : 10 20
Output : 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  (Except 11)
```

the java code is

```
class Test 
{ 
    // Method to print unique digit numbers 
    // in range from l to r. 
    static void printUnique(int l, int r) 
    { 
        // Start traversing the numbers 
        for (int i=l ; i<=r ; i++) 
        { 
            int num = i; 
            boolean visited[] = new boolean[10]; 

            // Find digits and maintain its hash 
            while (num != 0) 
            { 
                // if a digit occcurs more than 1 time 
                // then break 
                if (visited[num % 10]) 
                    break; 

                visited[num%10] = true; 

                num = num/10; 
            } 

            // num will be 0 only when above loop 
            // doesn't get break that means the 
            // number is unique so print it. 
            if (num == 0) 
                System.out.print(i + " "); 
        } 
    }
```

here l and r are the ranges.

my equivalent scala code is

```
def printUnique(l:int,r:int)
     | for(i <- l to r)
     | {
     | num=i
     | val z = new Array[Boolean](10)
     | while (num != 0)
     | {
     | if(z[num % 10])
<console>:8: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
       if(z[num % 10])
```

I am not sure about the error.can I get some help converting this code to scala in an optimized manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a predicate that determines whether a number has repeating digits:

```
def distinctDigits(n: Int): Boolean = {
   val s = n.toString
   s.length == s.distinct.length
 }
```

That can be used with `filter` to give the list you want

```
(10 to 20).filter(distinctDigits)
```

Comment: I hope question expects considering numbers like `232` as valid one. Instead of ` s.length == s.distinct.length` , using `s.distinct.length != 1` should give proper answer( excluding numbers with all digits are same)

Comment: @PraveenL how even we can assume 232 as valid? Question is does a nubmer has the unique digits or not? and 232 doen't has uniques numbers.

Comment: @tim here u have converted number to string..If I want to find all the good number falling between given range..A number is good if its every digit is larger than the sum of digits which are on the right side of that digit. For example 9620 is good number because 2 > 0, 6 > 2+0 and 9 > 6+2+0. I cannot write this code If I convert number to string..can u please help in coding this.

Comment: @pooja That is a different question, so ask it as a separate question on stackoverflow and I will answer it if I can.

Comment: @pooja Your question was asked by someone else, so see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52401515/7662670)

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code, I think, is that in Scala accessing an element of an `Array` or any other collection isn't done with square brackets, but instead with normal ones:

```
// wrong:
// array[index]

// correct:
array(index)
```

Anyway, an alternative solution in Scala, that doesn't rely on `String` methods and is similar in spirit to your original code, could look like this:

```
def getDigits(number: Int): Iterator[Int] =
  Iterator.iterate(number)(_ / 10).takeWhile(_ != 0).map(_ % 10)

def hasUniqueDigits(number: Int): Boolean = {
  val visited = Array.ofDim[Boolean](10)
  getDigits(number).forall {
    digit =>
      if (visited(digit)) false
      else {
        visited(digit) = true
        true
      }
  }
} 

def getUniqueDigitNumbers(left: Int, right: Int): IndexedSeq[Int] =
  left to right filter hasUniqueDigits

def printUnique(left: Int, right: Int): Unit =
  getUniqueDigitNumbers(left, right) foreach println
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this returns a stream of the number's digits,
// from right to left. It's lazily evaluated.
def digits(n: Int): Stream[Int] =
  if (n == 0) Stream.Empty
  else (n % 10) #:: digits(n / 10)

// Counts the number of a digit occurences instead of
// storing a flag in Array[Boolean]. In the latter case
// it would require `if`, while we don't need any here.
// It's lazy as well, so will not need excessive evaluations.
def copies(d: Stream[Int]) = {
  val z = new Array[Int](10)
  d.map { i => z(i) = z(i) + 1; z(i) }
}

// Here we check if any digit has more than 1 occurence. The
// evaluation will stop as soon as such a digit found.
def test(n: Int) = copies(digits(n)).exists(_ > 1)

10 to 20 filterNot (test) foreach (println)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it

```
def getDistinctNumbers(start: Int, end: Int): List[Int] = {
  if (start > end) return List.empty
  val hasUniqueDigits: Int => Boolean = a => {
    val str = a.toString
    str.split("").distinct.size == str.length
  }

 // From the range filter only the elements which have unique digits
 (start to end).toList.filter(hasUniqueDigits)
}
```

Comment: But `hasUniqueDigits` is not a monad, it's merely a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def isUniqueDigits(n:Long):Boolean={
 import scala.annotation.tailrec
  @tailrec
  val x = if(n<0) -n else n
  val list:List[Int] = x match{
   case x if(x>=0 && x<10) => List(x.toInt)
   case x if(x>=10)  =>toDig(x/10):+(x%10).toInt
   }
  list == list.distinct
  }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> (738 to 778).filter(isUniqueDigits(_))
res14: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 745, 746, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752,
753, 754, 756, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 768, 769)
```